# Linear model does not perform well while lasso performs well

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I have multi collinearity in my data, but as I have heard, that should not affect the prediction power of my model, but linear regression does terribly while lasso is doing just fine. May the problem be something other than multi-collinearity?